# How to make an array loop indefinitely?

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, infinite-loop

I have a list of names:

```
@names = qw(John Peter Michael);
```

I want to take 2 values from it, so I get John and Peter. If I want to take 2 more - I get Michael and John. 1 more - Peter. 3 more - Michael John and Peter, and so on.

I've started writing a subroutine where a global index ID would be set and remembered, and would reset itself to zero once it reaches scalar limit of an array, but then I read somewhere that Perl arrays "remember" the position they were looped.

Is that true or am I misunderstanding something? Is there a way to do my task an easy way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not that hard to roll your own iterator, but [`perlfaq4`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-handle-circular-lists%3F) has your need covered:

---

> ### How do I handle circular lists?
>
> (contributed by brian d foy)
>
> If you want to cycle through an array endlessly, you can increment the
>   index modulo the number of elements in the array:
>
> ```
> my @array = qw( a b c );
> my $i = 0;
> while( 1 ) {
>     print $array[ $i++ % @array ], "\n";
>     last if $i > 20;
> }
> ```
>
> You can also use [`Tie::Cycle`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::Cycle) to use a scalar that always has the next element of the circular array:
>
> ```
> use Tie::Cycle;
> tie my $cycle, 'Tie::Cycle', [ qw( FFFFFF 000000 FFFF00 ) ];
> print $cycle; # FFFFFF
> print $cycle; # 000000
> print $cycle; # FFFF00
> ```
>
> The [`Array::Iterator::Circular`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Iterator::Circular) creates an iterator object for circular arrays:
>
> ```
> use Array::Iterator::Circular;
> my $color_iterator = Array::Iterator::Circular->new(
>     qw(red green blue orange)
>     );
> foreach ( 1 .. 20 ) {
>     print $color_iterator->next, "\n";
> }
> ```

---

### The roll-your-own variety

The subroutine is really quite simple (implemented as `circularize` in the code below). The value of `$i` is retained in `$colors`'s scope, so no need for state variables:

```
sub circularize {
  my @array = @_;
  my $i = 0;
  return sub { $array[ $i++ % @array ] }
}

my $colors = circularize( qw( red blue orange purple ) ); # Initialize

print $colors->(), "\n" for 1 .. 14; # Use
```

Comment: I do like the roll-your-own method although it needs to be tweaked a little to meet the original spec of getting N elements.  I thought about doing something similar but state just popped out of my head onto the page.  Very nice.

Answer (score 3):

I never fully understood that mechanism (is it only on foreach?).  I would just use state values, e.g.:

```
my @names = qw(John Peter Michael);

sub GetNames($) {
  my $count = shift;
  my @result = ();

  state $index = 0;
  state $length = scalar(@names);

  while($count--) {
    push(@result, $names[($index++ % $length)]);
  }
  return @result;
}


print join(", ", GetNames(2)), "\n\n";
print join(", ", GetNames(4)), "\n";
```

Outputs:

John, Peter

Michael, John, Peter, Michael

Comment: See my answer on how this can be done without relying on `state` variables

Comment: Need `use feature 'state';` (or `use v5.10;`).  @Zaid, I like your answer (+1) but as for `state` feature -- it is conceptually simpler than a closure.

Comment: To each his own :)

Comment: Comments.  Relying on global `@names` in the sub limits its use. The `$length` need not be `state`, and `scalar` isn't needed, just `my $len = @names;`. I don't see the benefit of using a prototype here (and it is not used in the example).

Comment: True true... not a very useful snippet of code.  @Zaid's code is definitely more geared towards re-use.

Comment: @KrisOye I didn't mean that and I don't think so -- all these are easily remedied. I think that this is one good solution for the problem.